# Almacenar Archivos pdf en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf, binary-files

Estoy creando una aplicación web y necesito guardar archivos **PDF** en mi base de datos, **los archivos no sobrepasan los 5 MB**, ¿es buena práctica almacenarlos en la base de datos con tipo de datos varbinary? ¿O hay una forma mejor de almacenar archivos PDF?

Nota: **Debo hacer un full text search en todos esos archivos almacenados**

Comment: Debés tener en cuenta que tu pregunta está basada en opiniones, por lo tanto lo más probable es que termine [cerrada](/help/closed-questions). Leé [ask].

Comment: No, en mi opinión no es una buena práctica, los archivos van por un lado y los datos por otro. En la base de datos almacenas el path del archivo y en un fileserver los archivos en sí.

Comment: No puedes hacer búsqueda de texto en un archivo binario.

Answer (score 1):

No es una buena práctica almacenar archivos en la base de datos. Lo que se sugiere es guardarlos en un servidor de archivos y en la base de datos almacenar únicamente la ruta. Sin embargo, esa parte puede ser considerada una opinión como muchas "buenas prácticas".

Lo importante en este caso en particular es que no te servirá almacenarlos como varbinary si luego pretendes usarlos para buscar texto en ellos. Para poder utilizar FULLTEXT search, los datos tienen que ser de tipo caracter (normalmente varchar(max)) para que el motor los pueda identificar como texto.

Una alternativa sería que obtuvieras todo el texto de los archivos y los guardaras en la base de datos, pero eso implicaría duplicar información (lo que también es considerado una mala práctica).

Lo ideal sería que el almacenamiento y búsquedas sean mediante un gestor de archivos.